# Sharepoint 2013 Help with check list that auto refreshes weekly

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, recurring-events, onenote, checklist

[image]
I am trying to get a weekly check list that our team uses from onenote onto our team sharepoint page. I would like the check boxes and names to auto clear weekly. Right now we have a shared notebook with weekly pages in onenote that we update. I tried making a custom list but it doesn't provide a dropdown menu for the completed by section. The tasks remain the same each week. So I am just looking for a method to track the Analyst that completed them.

UPDATE-
I kind of got it to work but I'm struggling to clean up the view. I'd like to remove the sections circled in red. I'd also like it to auto clear the "completed by" field daily.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Tasks and you can change the view by changing the style of it from 'Default' to 'Basic Table'. There is no way to clear the column without writing a job that runs daily.